# TypeError: TopDownBDD100KPoseDataset: TopDownCocoDataset.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dataset_info'

Tags: python, openmmlab

i was trying to run the test from this code https://github.com/SysCV/bdd100k-models/tree/main/pose

when i try run the pose test I get this error
code :

```
!python test.py /content/bdd100k-models/pose/configs/pose/hrnet_w32_256x192_1x_pose_bdd100k.py --gpu_collect --format-dir /content/
```

error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mmcv/utils/registry.py", line 51, in build_from_cfg return obj_cls(**args) TypeError: TopDownCocoDataset.init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dataset_info'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last): File "/content/bdd100k-models/pose/test.py", line 132, in main() File "/content/bdd100k-models/pose/test.py", line 89, in main dataset = build_dataset(cfg.data.test, dict(test_mode=True)) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mmpose/datasets/builder.py", line 44, in build_dataset dataset = build_from_cfg(cfg, DATASETS, default_args) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mmcv/utils/registry.py", line 54, in build_from_cfg raise type(e)(f'{obj_cls.name}: {e}') TypeError: TopDownBDD100KPoseDataset: TopDownCocoDataset.init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dataset_info'
```

how i can solve it ?

my current version
mmcv-full is 1.7.1
mmcls is 0.25.0
mmdetis 2.27.0
segmentation is 0.30.0
mmpose is 0.18.0

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the relevant parts of the code as text and not a link to a project.